# Encrypted Hard Disk troubleshooting

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, password, performance, encryption

**I have problems to read an encypted  hard disk.** Unfortunatly I do not remember if I did encryted with Time machine or Disk Utitlity. I think I did it with the first one (Time Machine) as I used the disk as a buck up.

The issue is that **When I plug it in it asks me for a password as soon as I write it it blocks or freeze.** I have no problems remembering the password. it is no a problem with the Capitals tab.

I would apreciate any help - I have lots of files other than the back up. Fotos, movies, etc, necesary for a documentary .

I have a Macbookair 2011  1,8 GHz Intel Core i7. Mac os 10.7.5
The hard drive is a 2TB WD Elements. Mac formated.

Answer (score 2):

You must have enabled FileVault,
therefore your disk this
encrypted, you go to: System preferences / security and privacy / FileVault.
if enabled it so you disable,
it should take some time
why he will decrypt your disk, then restart and everything returns to normal.

for more information: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156